# Finding the distinct count from a cassandra column using Tableau

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, tableau-api

I am a beginner in Tableau. I have successfully connected Tableau with Cassandra.

I am facing an issue now.
I am trying to get the distinct count (unique) value from a given column..
The database which I have is like 17 million. (Cassandra DB)

[image]

I even tried count (Distinct) as shown above. But it is not working as expected.

Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to read this to understand more about cassandra and distinct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548788/select-distinct-cql-ignores-where-clause

Comment: Can you describe what's the behavior you expect and what is the actual behavior?

Comment: I am trying to get the unique count -- (similar to GroupBy concept) -- this screenname -- has some number of tweets. like that.

Comment: Actual Behavior - the tableau is not giving me any data count. Since it is not relational database structure schema.