# Execute extract on Tableau for distinct count using HLL

Tags: postgresql, tableau-api, distinct-values, hyperloglog

I have a somewhat huge table (130 million rows), that I am able to crunch on the same server in under 10 minutes, and produce a slimmed-down, pre-aggregated table, that works just fine and everyone is happy to use it.

The table is grouped by around 6 columns, and the rest are aggregated with `SUM()` or a variety of `COUNT(DISTINCT myColumn)` that's optimized with [HLL](https://github.com/citusdata/postgresql-hll).

```
hll_union_agg(hll_add(hll_empty(15, 4), hll_hash_bigint(my_column)))
```

People who use this small resulting table, can group by just 1 or 2 of the original columns, to get even a broader summary. Only at the final step the actual count is produced with

```
hll_cardinality(hll_union_agg(my_intermediary_hll_set))
```

Results are produced in milliseconds.

The problem is moving this to [Tableau](https://www.tableau.com/) as an extract in Hyper, because people want to use it there. Tableau doesn't know about HLL, and it wants to do the distinct-count itself. However pushing all of that raw data is extremely slow (like 5 hours slow).

I am willing to compromise on speed, but not by going from 10 minutes to 5 hours. Is there a way to transfer the set, that is currently represented as HLL, as a whole column? Like an array or JSON or something?

I found a similar question here, but it's more about Cassandra than about Tableau extracts.

[Finding the distinct count from a cassandra column using Tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889949/finding-the-distinct-count-from-a-cassandra-column-using-tableau)

**To sum it up:**
How do I pass in pre-aggregated rows to Tableau, and still be able to produce valid `COUNT(DISTINCT x)` calculations on Tableau side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue using [pass-through SQL functions](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_passthrough.html) in Tableau. After adding the data source (LIVE only) that contains HLL columns, creating a custom computed column using an expression like this:

```
rawsqlagg_int("hll_cardinality(hll_union_agg(%1))", [Set of entities])
```

I got the result that I needed. Amazing and fast.